# DataFormatString for Boolean column

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with dynamic datasource.

I add column in codebehind .

```
BoundField col=new BundField(); 
col.DataField="Active";
col.DataFormatString=//DataFormatString;
gridview1.Columns.Add(col);
```

How do set yes/no for boolean column ?

Answer (score 1):

**I use this code for VB:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
    <ItemTemplate><%#IIf(Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString()), "Yes", "No")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**And this should work for C# (untested):**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
    <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done that with SQL, when selecting data as:

```
select id, fname, (case  when Active = 'true' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) AS Active from tblName
```

Now no need of formatting it anymore the returned column Active is replaced with another column with the same name but that contains the values of Yes/No. 
I assumed your column active is a bit column that contains either true/false, but if something else replace the true/false with your values

Comment: But what if you need to use the boolean value before you display it? This method will break that unless you check for a 'yes' string or a 'no' string when you need to use it. Good idea; but only when you're just gonna view the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the solutions above using DataFormatString do not work for me in a GridView.

What worked for me was to use a template column, which I was trying to avoid...

[Can I convert a boolean to Yes/No in a ASP.NET GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216833/can-i-convert-a-boolean-to-yes-no-in-a-asp-net-gridview)

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this

```
dataformatstring="{0:Yes/No}"
```

Answer (score -2):

use dataformatstring="{0:Yes/No}";

Comment: still printing: False  True